# AdoptOpenJDK11 choice on Linux

Tags: java, linux

I would like to download [AdoptOpenJDK11](https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=openj9#unknown) on linux but I am stuck about the difference of version proposed.
Could someone explains me the difference between these linux's version? 
[image: platforms choice]
Above all the Linux part.

Comment: Even if I did answer this already, I think a question like this would be more at home in https://superuser.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ppc64le and s390x are different hardware architectures, used mostly (virtually only) on some servers. x64 is for the typical, Intel/AMD processor based computers.
2. "Large Heap" is for users who need to utilize larger RAM sizes than ~53 Gigabytes, which also is virtually only for servers. (Source: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/341)

Ergo, if you are installing this on a laptop/desktop computer, you will want to choose the simple "x64" one. While the Large Heap build might work (I don't actually know if it does), it is not built for your use-case.

Comment: Thank you for these details. I would like to install it on a Virtual Machine for production usage. I'll go for the simple "x64".